# Can't find Vector in Windows store app

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, data-visualization

I can't find Vector class in Windows store app. I understand this is available in WPF but can I find a similar custom implementation in Windows store app.

I am trying to [enter link description here](http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/507#.Uuc-whC6bIU) for placing labels on PieChart in Windows store app.

Vinod

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is something missing in your question. What do you mean by "Vector class"? If you mean something like `Platform::Vector` or `std::Vector` from C++ then you can use a `List` class when developing for Windows Store with .NET. If you mean a label associated with a PieChart then there is no such thing as a PieChart in the Windows Runtime libraries, though I have ported the chart control from Silverlight Toolkit in my WinRT XAML Toolkit and there is a sample [here](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit.Sample/Views/Controls/ChartTestPage.xaml). It has labels, but displays them in a legend box to the side of the chart. If you really need them to be linked to the pie slices then you would probably need to implement something similar to what was done in the article you linked to, possibly using the port of the `Chart` control in WinRT XAML Toolkit. You can install the control using NuGet from [here](http://www.nuget.org/packages/winrtxamltoolkit.controls.DataVisualization).

Comment: I am able to find the center position of PieData point but the issue is in some case the lable goes beyond the pie slice area.

Comment: There is probably some angle property related to each data point that is either exposed or that you can expose and then based on that you can render a label using some custom code.

Comment: can you suggest the code to find the angle of pie slice?

Comment: I think you'd need to convert it from `PieDataPoint.ActualOffsetRatio`  and `PieDataPoint.ActualRatio` in a similar way the [`PieSeries`](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization/Charting/Series/PieSeries.cs) does it in `ConvertRatioOfRotationToPoint()`